# Getting the right navigation and main left (without using float)

Tags: html, css

trying to make a simple project where the left side will be navigating and the right main content. The problem is that I do not want to use the float: left, float: right function. Is there any other option to get this effect? Below is the photo:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jaBF.png)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
}

/* product section */

.products {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 853px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.product-card {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 
 padding: 2%;
 flex: 1 16%;
 
 background-color: #FFF;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.product-image img {
 width: 100%;
}

.product-info {
 margin-top: auto;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

h5 {
    color: #C00;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* product section end */

.nav {
  
  max-width: 853px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.nav .parent li a{
  padding: 10px 12px 10px 20px;
  background: #429840;
  color: white;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}

.nav .child li a{ background: #ddd; color:#333;}

.nav .parent a:hover{ background: #429855;}
.nav .child a:hover{ background: #429855;}

ul.parent > li:hover > ul.child{ 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px; top: 0;
}


ul.parent > li{ position: relative;}

ul.child{ display: none; }

.plus{ float: right; }
```

```html
  <div class="nav">
  <ul class="parent">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About <span class="plus">+</span></a>
      <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#">What We do?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Awords</a></li>
      </ul>    
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Products <span class="plus">+</span></a>
      <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Desktop</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  
  
  <section class="products">
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box1</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box2</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box3</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box4</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box5</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box6</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box7</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box8</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box9</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
   <div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
   </div>
   <div class="product-info">
    <h5>box10</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
 </section>
```

I tried to use a flexbox, but everything starts break...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap everything and flex it too.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* product section */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 853px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.product-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2%;
  flex: 1 16%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.product-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.product-info {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h5 {
  color: #C00;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* product section end */

.nav {
  max-width: 853px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.nav .parent li a {
  padding: 10px 12px 10px 20px;
  background: #429840;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.nav .child li a {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #333;
}

.nav .parent a:hover {
  background: #429855;
}

.nav .child a:hover {
  background: #429855;
}

ul.parent>li:hover>ul.child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
}

ul.parent>li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.child {
  display: none;
}

.plus {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="parent">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About <span class="plus">+</span></a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#">What We do?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Awords</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Products <span class="plus">+</span></a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Desktop</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <section class="products">
    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box1</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box2</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box3</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box4</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box5</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box6</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box7</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box8</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box9</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://www.ayearofboxes.com/wp-content/themes/ayearofboxes/assets/svg/box-closed.svg" alt="90gsm">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>box10</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: it is a problem because at full resolution both nav and main content are very distant from each other (on small resolution looks like I wanted), but thanks for that, i trying to fix it somehow

Answer (score 0):

If you use position absolute on each of the sections you will be able to use `left:0` and `right:0`. See below and hope that helps.

```
.nav {
    max-width: 853px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index:2;
}
section.products {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I would like both nav and main content to be in max-width: 853px;

Comment: @k.drm looks like Rudi below has you sorted but what I would have done is set the width of each section if you need it to be within 853px. So give .nav a width of 200px and .products a width of 653px. Or whatever ratio you deem fit.